# Simple change of text in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My fuction simply won't work and i don't know why... What i am trying to do is to change the language of this HTML file and when i click simply nothing happens and i can't understard what is the wrong with this code any help would be apreciated.. note that i am new in HTML/css/javascript and i been working with this for around 1 week

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
  <title>Βιογραφικο Σημειωμα</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    fuction EN(){
     document.getElementById('Head').innerHTML = "CV Resume";
      




}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="EN()" value="EN"/>
  <h1 id="Head">Βιογραφικο Σημειωμα</h1>
  <h3>Πρωσοπικες Πληροφοριες:</h3>
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" height="150" width="150" alt=" " align="left" >  
  <br><br>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <ul>
          
           <li id="name"><b>Ονομα :</b> <span itemprop="name">Αχιλλεας Ματσουκας</span></li>
           <li><b>Ημερομηνια γεννησης :</b><span itemprop="birthDate"> 20/7/1996 (20)</span></li>
 <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
           <li><b>Διευθηνση : </b><span itemprop="streetAddress"> Κριτσα 4 , Λαμια </span></div>
           <li><b>Επικοινωνια : </b> 1.<span itemprop="telephone">2223105258</span> 2.Achilleasmatsoukas@gmail.com </li></p>

    </ul>
<br><br>
  <h3>Σπουδες:</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Αποφοιτος Γενικου Λυκειου</li>
    <li>Κατοχος Level 1 Πτυχειου Barista</li>
    <li>Φοιτητης για Πτυχειο Πληροφορικης</li>
  </ol>
  <h3>Εργασιακη Εμπειρια</h3>
    <ol>
    
      <li>4 μηνες σε ξενοδοχειο ως <span itemprop="jobTitle">Barista</span></li>
      <li>Γνωσεις σερβιτορου</li>
      <li>Βοηθως <span itemprop="jobTitle">Προγραμματιστη</span> σε μαγαζι επισκευων</li>      
  </ol>
  <h3>Αλλες Γνωσεις:</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Πτυχειο επιπεδου Campebridge στα Αγγλικα </li>
    <li>Γνωση χρησης Η/Υ</li>
  </ol>
</div>
                   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo in script...change it to function

Comment: Check the spelling of javascript keywords in your code

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors. I'm downvoting this question because you could have seen the problem that way.

Comment: this such a waste of your time sorry.. i am gonna delete the post

Comment: @AxilleasMatsoukas Remember to always look at your console output for any errors! Finds typos like these instantly.

Comment: @Barmar Well, to be fair, console errors tend to be cryptic and only tangentially related to the actual problem....

Comment: @Feathercrown True, some error messages are not clear to newbies. But this one tells him there's a syntax error, and exactly what line it's on, then he should see the typo.

Comment: @Barmar True, true.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really simple; but you're getting the logic right, which is good.
The mistake is...
*drumroll*
...a typo.

When you declare `EN()`, you accidentally wrote `fuction` instead of `function`.

Answer (score 1):

As the above post mentioned, there was a typo. Here is the code that I tested and it works without the typo, just so you can see how minor the error was:

```
function EN(){
     document.getElementById('Head').innerHTML = "CV Resume";
   };
```